# How to filter an union type based on a condition

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an union type of:

```
type FooBar = {foo: 'a'} | {foo: 'b'} | {foo: 'c', bar: 'c'};
```

Is there a way to create a subset that only contains foo?

```js
type OnlyFoo = SomeFilter<FooBar, 'foo'>;
// type OnlyFoo = {foo: 'a'} | {foo: 'b'};
```

Comment: Only contain `foo` and no other property ?

Comment: Yes, or filtering out ones that has `bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a distributive conditional type that first filters by the desired key (`foo` for example) and then filters any type that has any extra keys by testing if `Exclude<FooBar, 'foo'>` is `never`:

```
type FilterByProp<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends Record<K, any> ? 
    Exclude<keyof T, K> extends never ? T : 
    never : never;

type FooBar = {foo: 'a'} | {foo: 'b'} | {foo: 'c', bar: 'c'};
type OnlyFoo = FilterByProp<FooBar, 'foo'>
```